# Changing Raster symbol values (Unique Values) in ArcObjects?

Tags: raster, arcobjects

I want to change Raster properties symbology using with Arcobjects. Unique Values change as per below attached snapshot.

```
Dim pWSFact As IWorkspaceFactory
Set pWSFact = New RasterWorkspaceFactory

'Getting Path
Dim pRWSpace As IRasterWorkspace
Set pRWSpace = pWSFact.OpenFromFile(strFolder, 0)

'Open Raster from path
Dim pRDSet As IRasterDataset
Set pRDSet = pRWSpace.OpenRasterDataset(DestFile)

'Convert RasterDataset to raster layer
Dim pRLyr As IRasterLayer
Set pRLyr = New RasterLayer
pRLyr.CreateFromDataset pRDSet
Dim pRReder As IRasterRenderer
Set pRReder = pRLyr.Renderer
Dim pBndCnt As Long
pBndCnt = pRLyr.BandCount
If (pBndCnt = 1) Then

'Document calling
Dim pmxdoc As IMxDocument
Set pmxdoc = ThisDocument

'Set map
Dim pmap As IMap
Set pmap = pmxdoc.FocusMap

'Add layer to Map
pmap.AddLayer pRLyr

Dim pRaster As IRaster
Set pRaster = pRLyr.Raster

Dim pRasterProps As IRasterProps
Set pRasterProps = pRaster

Dim pRSCRR As IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer
Set pRSCRR = New RasterStretchColorRampRenderer

Dim pRStch As IRasterStretch
Set pRStch = pRSCRR
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do? change from Uniquevalue to raster stretch or the other way round?

Comment: Hi chamiddor, After adding Raster in ArcMap, Raster Symbology default coming Stretched but i want Unique Values option could you please tell me how to set Unique Values through ArcObjects.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the example here
[How to create a raster unique value renderer](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/77da7a38-c696-407d-b73c-ddb36def6032.htm)

> This article shows how to create a raster unique value renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using this code:

```
Function unvrender(rstrdataset As IRasterDataset) As IRasterRenderer

    //get the raster attribute table and the size of the table
    Dim colorRamp As IRandomColorRamp
    Set colorRamp = New RandomColorRamp
    colorRamp.size = 2
    colorRamp.Seed = 1
    colorRamp.CreateRamp False


    //Create unique value renderer
    Dim uvRenderer As IRasterUniqueValueRenderer
    Set uvRenderer = New RasterUniqueValueRenderer

    Dim rasterRenderer As IRasterRenderer
    Set rasterRenderer = uvRenderer
    Set rasterRenderer.Raster = rstrdataset.CreateDefaultRaster
    rasterRenderer.Update

    uvRenderer.HeadingCount = 1
    uvRenderer.Heading(0) = "Band"
    uvRenderer.ClassCount(0) = 2
    uvRenderer.Field = "Value"

    Dim fillSymbol As ISimpleFillSymbol
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim col As IColor
    Set col = New RgbColor
    col.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    Dim col1 As IColor
    Set col1 = New RgbColor
    col1.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    uvRenderer.AddValue 0, 0, "0"
    uvRenderer.Label(0, 0) = "0"
    Set fillSymbol = New SimpleFillSymbol
    fillSymbol.Color = col
    uvRenderer.Symbol(0, 0) = fillSymbol


    uvRenderer.AddValue 0, 1, "1"
    uvRenderer.Label(0, 1) = "1"
    Set fillSymbol = New SimpleFillSymbol
    fillSymbol.Color = col1
    uvRenderer.Symbol(0, 1) = fillSymbol

 Set unvrender = rasterRenderer

End Function
```

Comment: Very nice, so the example at the link in my answer helped? I think it was really that what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks you schmiddor your providing like very usefully for me. Actually i am working on Raster vectorization tool. before running that tool need to set raster unique values option other wise my not working.

Comment: So if it was useful for you please mark it as answer or vote it at least.